# How can I protect my website with cisco ASA Firewall 5520 and do url and web filtering?

Tags: networking, firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

I've got a cisco ASA firewall 5520 on my small organization's network, and i'm quite new to ASAs as i have just finished my SNAF course and need time and experience.

My question is how can i protect my web site with this security appliance in terms of configuration? I basically just got the basic configuration on it, but indeed to improve the configuration so that i can have my web site protected, and  to be able to do Packet filtering, Url filtering And content filtering as well, since many of my of users are accessing undesirable web sites, while others are doing a lot of of downloads which is consuming most of my bandwidth .

Can any one share with me how can i block all that? How to protect my web site?
is there Any useful step by step guide that can guide me?

Comment: 5520 sounds like massive overkill if you're truly a "small organization".  Probably a 5505 would've been sufficient.

Comment: Sounds like you need to hire someone to come in and work with you setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

Options for web content filtering on the ASA 5520 include:

- [Integrated Websense functionality](http://www.websense.com/support/article/t-kbarticle/Configure-PIX-Firewall-ASA-for-Websense-Integration), which refers to an internal Websense installation to allow/deny URL's.
- A [Cisco ASA Content Security module](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6823/index.html) with extra licensing, which uses Trend Micro filtering.
- Another appliance or proxy solution external to the Cisco device.